# Component Based Servicing (CBS) affects shutdown duration in Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

I tested UPS shutdown in case of power failure on Windows Server 2016 + APC Smart UPS + NUT.

In some moment NUT has sent shutdown command to Windows. But instead of real shutdown I observed screen with "*Getting ready your server*" or something like it, I do not remember exactly. Screen like it were some updates installing during shutdown process. But server has been configured for *manual* upates. And I have checked and installed all updates couple of hours before this.

It took 20-25 minutes for shutdown process to complete. Fortunately UPS did not turn off the power (due to some config errors). But in real situation with correct configs UPS would remove AC power from server in 3 minutes after shutdown command.

Later I've investigated logs and have found that CBS (Component Based Servicing) has began some maitenanace tasks several munites before shutdown. So Windows waited for it to complete.

Approximate timings:

```
15:36:55 shutdown command with 30 sec delay (shutdown.exe /f /s /t 30)
15:37:25 user logoff
about 15:55 shutdown has completed
```

From CBS.log:

```
2019-05-08 15:34:59, Info                  CBS    Maint: begin deep clean
...
...
2019-05-08 15:37:26, Info                  CBS    Trusted Installer signaled for shutdown, going to exit.
2019-05-08 15:37:26, Info                  CBS    A system shutdown was initiated while idle scavenging was running
2019-05-08 15:37:26, Info                  CBS    Shtd: Prepare for shutdown processing.
2019-05-08 15:37:26, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.2273.1.4, Update: 4103720-19196_neutral_PACKAGE, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Absent, targeted: Absent, limit: Absent, selected: Default
2019-05-08 15:37:26, Info                  CBS    SetProgressMessage: progressMessageStage: 0, ExecuteState: ExecuteStateNone, SubStage: 0
2019-05-08 15:37:26, Info                  CBS    Shtd: PreshutdownTimeout: 3600000ms, BlockTimeIncrement: 900000ms
2019-05-08 15:37:26, Info                  CBS    Shtd: progress thread started
```

It seems for me a problem that any process can affect shudown. Especially when server must shutdown as soon as possible.

Questions:

1. Is this a behaviour of only WinServer2016? What about WinServer2012R2?
2. Is it possible to make forced but correct shutdown to override such busy processes?

Comment: `installing during shutdown process. But server has been configured for anual upates. And I have checked and installed all updates couple of ours before this.` What is an 'anual update'? You also need to provide what events were recorded in the setup event log after the shutdown was initiated. `in real situation with correct configs UPS would remove AC power from server in 3 minutes after shutdown command`. Why? The server should power off after shutdown completes.

Comment: (1) Sorry, it should read _manual_.  (2) The only way to start server (and any other computer) automatically _by_ _UPS_ is to cycle power off-on after AC returns. And BIOS should be set to power on after AC returns.

Comment: (1) ... and _hours_

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this, not in a way that would be any faster at least. A better solution would be to monitor systems for a pending reboot, which is obviously the case here, and reboot them. Systems should not be sitting out there for weeks in a pending reboot state anyway.